# how to connect node.js rest client with UI

Tags: node.js, node.js-client

I am new to node.js. I have a question regarding connecting my node.js with UI. I have a node.js server which produces rest API with basic authentication. I have written a node.js rest client which will use this APi and print the Json in the command prompt. I need solution for how to connect this node.js client with my UI. for example I have index.html file how can i get this client connected to me index.html. or is there any other way through which i can get the JSon produced by my client in the UI. I need few suggestion on this I will really appreciate every suggestion thanks in advance .

Comment: please see expressjs.com for things to learn what you are searching for, you will also learn new things and it is a type of framework for node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Rest API in place, you can use jquery to call this API and modify the page. See the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [an example](http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-get-json.html).
Basically your code should call the rest service, and use the returned data to modify the page.

Comment: Yes you are right but what if i need t do basic Authentication.. can you suggest me something

Comment: Look at passportjs - http://passportjs.org/

Comment: It is going to help me connecting node.js client with the UI